# Looking at buying a used Dodge Journey or Minivan - squeeling sound while pressing gas?

Tags: noise, dodge, caravan

I'm probably leaning towards the Dodge Journey. I've test driven a few vehicles and I've noticed a high pitched squeel from the engine when I press the accelerator. I've read online that it might just be a belt issue. Is this a common issue with these vehicles and what else should I be looking for before I buy the vehicle?

Edit: The vehicle range I'm looking at is 2007-2010 Dodge Journeys. The squeeling noise only seems to be happening on acceleration.. what concerns me is that this seems to be happening on a number of Journeys. I looked at YouTube and this seems to be fairly close to the sound I'm hearing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVszZ_7ZIjY

Comment: This is a huge topic, and a very broad question. How many miles are there on this car? What year is it? The things you look for vary. I wouldn't give the exhaust a second thought on a 6 month old car with 10k miles on it. A 15 year old car is going to have a long list of things to look at so you can determine the value and what you should pay.  Will they let you do a compression test? Can you take it to a mechanic to have it looked over before you buy it? If not, and you don't generally know what to look for, I would not recommend buying it. Can you make this question more specific?

Comment: I'm not voting to close this question. It is a bit broad though. If you could add some more details as @cdunn has suggested, please do so. We do welcome you to Mechanics.SE, though!! :o)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll edit the question and try to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

**Doesn't sound like a belt**

The sounds in the video you posted don't sound like a squealing belt.

If your researched has revealed concerns regarding the vehicle I suggest you abandon your desire to own it.

The low hum that seems to change frequency without the car changing in speed is concerning.  It makes me think transmission but there is too little information to nail it down as the comments to your question illiterate.

Not a squeaking belt though, IMO.